# Using a query for Single field in Access Report

Tags: sql, ms-access, report

I am new to access. I have a report with a query(Q1) as its data source. Is it possible to use another query(Q2) only for one field in the same report?

My main query is:

```
SELECT PersonTotalHours.*, Person.*
FROM PersonTotalHours
INNER JOIN Person 
ON PersonTotalHours.LastName = Person.LastName;
```

My report's structure is like this:

```
Report header
_____________
Page header
_____________
Lastname header
_____________
report details
_____________
Lastname Footer
_____________
PageFooter
```

As you can see, in the report I group my data using the Lastname column then I show details about each peron for current year.

I need to show short form of data about former years of each person in the Last name header (somewhere before the detailed data).

Second query is like this:

```
SELECT PersonTotalHours.MA, PersonTotalHours.Year, Sum(PersonTotalHours.Hours) AS Sum
FROM PersonTotalHours
GROUP BY PersonTotalHours.MA, PersonTotalHours.Year
```

I use this for short form of data.

**Important** point is that the number of rows can be different. Person A might have 0 previous years and another person has more than 5.

How is it possible to use the second query for parts of report data?

Comment: @Fionnuala the last name is no problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solve the problem using a subreport.

http://www.simply-access.com/Multiple-Queries-in-Report.html